# Want number to displayed with trailing zeros in csv file ( ex. 5 should be 5.00). what should be the code for xslt file

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, number-formatting, xsl-fo

whenever i download my data in csv format the no. appear as 5 ,10, 11 instead it should display as 5.00, 10.00, 11.00 and so on

```
<xsl:when test="$type='D'">
 <xsl:value-of select="format-number(amountInAccountCurrency/amount, '#####0.##')"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="$type='C'">
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(amountInAccountCurrency/amount, '#####0.##')"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
```

used above code for and have also used ###0.00 still not working

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] with input and desired output values?

Comment: You seem to be producing a text output - so what does XSL-FO have to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(amountInAccountCurrency/amount, '0.00')"/>
```

Untested, because you did not provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

---

Do note that the result of formatting a number to display trailing zeros is a **string**. To make sure it is interpreted as such by the target application, you should enclose it in double-quotes when producing a CSV output. If you don't, the target application (notably a spreadsheet) might consider it to be a number and strip the trailing zeros.